# Floats.tryParse() in Guava

Tags: java, guava

I found the only method:

```
Ints.tryParse()
```

Is there any similar methods for Double/Float in Guava?

If not, what are the causes of absence?

Thx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We (well, I) have an [implementation](http://codereview.appspot.com/6354088/) in the works that finished code review less than 24 hours ago. It should hopefully be released in 14.0.  (The other integral types besides `int`, including the unsigned types, are going in a separate code review that's just started.)

Comment: Thx for answer, Louis. And thank you for this wonderful library.